# chr equivalent for Unicode in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to initialize a Widestring in Delphi 7 but I can't use `chr` function which is ANSI

```
var
  ws : Widestring;
begin

 ws := chr($FFFF) + chr($FFFF) + chr($FFFF);

end;
```

What can I use, then ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a Delphi compiler here, but can't you use something like a `#$...` character constant in the string? By the way, U+FFFF is an illegal character in Unicode; don't use it ever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a simply way to do what you wish. You can convert a `Word` into a `WideChar` with a simple cast:

```
WideChar($FFFF)
```

but you cannot concatenate `WideChar`. So this is a compiler error:

```
WideChar($FFFF) + WideChar($FFFF)
```

You could use a helper function to get the job done:

```
function InitialiseWideString(const chars: array of Word): WideString;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(chars));
  for i := 0 to high(chars) do
    Result[i+1] := WideChar(chars[i]);
end;
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
ws := InitialiseWideString([$0054, $0069, $006D, $0065, $0020, $0074, $006F, 
  $0020, $0075, $0070, $0067, $0072, $0061, $0064, $0065]);
```

Comment: Found easter egg: "Time to upgrade" :-).

Comment: @tz. Ah, nice to know that it wasn't all for nothing!!

Comment: Nice one, will add it to the company core library ;)