# What is the difference between of object and reference to?

Tags: delphi

What is the difference between

```
TFuncOfIntToString = reference to function(x: Integer): string;
```

and

```
TFuncOfIntToString = function(x: Integer): string of object;
```

I use the of object

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Let us consider the following three type declarations:

```
TProcedure = procedure;
TMethod = procedure of object;
TAnonMethod = reference to procedure;
```

These are all very similar to each other. In terms of calling instances of each of these three types, the calling code is identical. The differences arise in what can be assigned to variables of these types.

**Procedural types**

`TProcedure` is a [procedural type](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedural_Types#About_Procedural_Types). You can assign to a variable of type `TProcedure` something of this form:

```
procedure MyProcedure;
begin
end;
```

This is a non object-oriented procedure. You cannot assign an instance or class method to a `TProcedure` variable. However, you can assign a [static class method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Class_Static_Methods) to a `TProcedure` variable.

**Method pointers**

`TMethod` is a [method pointer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedural_Types#Method_Pointers). This is indicated by the presence of `of object`. When you have a variable of type `TMethod` you must assign either:

1. A instance method of an instantiated object, or
2. A class method.

So you can assign either of these:

```
procedure TMyClass.MyMethod;
begin
end;

class procedure TMyClass.MyClassMethod;
begin
end;
```

The big difference between a procedural type and a method pointer is that the latter contains a reference to both code and data. A method pointer is often known as a two-pointer procedural type. A variable that contains a method pointer contains references to the code and the instance/class to call it on.

Consider the following code:

```
var
  instance1, instance2: TMyClass;
  method1, method2: TMethod;
....
method1 := instance1.MyMethod;
method2 := instance2.MyMethod;
```

Now, although `method1` and `method2` refer to the same piece of code, they are associated with different object instances. So, if we call

```
method1();
method2();
```

We are invoking `MyMethod` on the two distinct instances. That code is equivalent to:

```
instance1.MyMethod();
instance2.MyMethod();
```

**Anonymous methods**

Finally we come to [anonymous methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi). These are even more general purpose than procedural types and method pointers. You can assign any of the following to a variable defined using the `reference to` syntax:

1. A plain non object-oriented procedure.
2. An instance method of an instantiated class.
3. A class method.
4. An anonymous method.

For example:

```
var
  AnonMethod: TAnonMethod;
....
AnonMethod := MyProcedure;            // item 1 above
AnonMethod := instance1.MyMethod;     // item 2
AnonMethod := TMyClass.MyClassMethod; // item 3
```

Anonymous methods, item 4 above, are those declared in-line in your code. For example:

```
var
  AnonMethod: TAnonMethod;
....
AnonMethod := procedure
  begin
    DoSomething;
  end;
```

The biggest benefit of anonymous methods when compared to the procedural types and method pointers is that they allow for [variable capture](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi#Anonymous_Methods_Variable_Binding). For example consider the following short program to illustrate:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
program VariableCapture;

type
  TMyFunc = reference to function(X: Integer): Integer;

function MakeFunc(Y: Integer): TMyFunc;
begin
  Result := function(X: Integer): Integer
    begin
      Result := X*Y;
    end;
end;

var
  func1, func2: TMyFunc;

begin
  func1 := MakeFunc(3);
  func2 := MakeFunc(-42);
  Writeln(func1(4));
  Writeln(func2(2));
  Readln;
end.
```

This has the following output:

```
12
-84
```

Comment: Why did I know it was you before I got to the bottom?

Comment: @MarjanVenema probably because David is one of the very few that give a huge explanation, basically a building block for the Delphi tag on SO (:

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo Well thank you, but I don't fully agree with you when you say "very few". I think there are a good number of active Delphi answerers here on SO that answer with good explanations. I won't name names, but those of us that are active here know who they are. We should all seek to encourage, through our voting, answers with explanation.

Comment: That is a great, great answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, although I'm not certain about greatness. Personally I'm a little sad that nobody found my easter egg yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932549/chr-equivalent-for-unicode-in-delphi-7/14932710#14932710

Answer (score 9):

The first is [anonymous method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi), the second is ordinary [method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Methods).