# example "virtual treeview" IterateSubtree in C++Builder XE-XE7

Tags: c++builder, virtualtreeview

I need an example how to use "virtual treeview" **IterateSubtree** in C++ Embarcadero Xe1-7.

**I have the problem with this code:**

```
void __fastcall TMyForm::BuSearchClick(TObject *)
{
  MyTreeView->IterateSubtree(NULL, SearchDataSomeId, (void*)&PNodeData, TVirtualNodeStates(), false, false);
}

void __fastcall TMyForm::SearchDataSomeId(TBaseVirtualTree*, PVirtualNode Node, void *Data, bool &Abort)
{
}
```

The compiler gives the following error:

```
[bcc32 Error] MyFile.cpp(363): E2034 Cannot convert 'void (_fastcall * (_closure )(TBaseVirtualTree *,TVirtualNode *,void *,bool &))(TBaseVirtualTree *,TVirtualNode *,void *,bool &)' to '_di_TVTGetNodeProc'
```

Comment: You should format the code so it's clear what is text, what is code.

Comment: "C++ embarcadero Xe1-7" what?

Comment: I am sorry  Rodrigo Gómez. Is it now ok?

Comment: @RodrigoGómez I fixed up the formatting.

Comment: There's more code here that you're not showing us. In particular, we need to know what `_di_TVTGetNodeProc` is.

Comment: Also, try changing `MyTreeView->IterateSubtree(NULL, SearchDataSomeId, ...` to `MyTreeView->IterateSubtree(NULL, &TMyForm::SearchDataSomeId`

Comment: from VirtualTrees.hpp  <br/>__interface TVTGetNodeProc;<br/>
typedef System::DelphiInterface<TVTGetNodeProc> _di_TVTGetNodeProc;<br/>
__interface TVTGetNodeProc  : public System::IInterface<br/>
{<br/>

public:<br/>
 virtual void __fastcall Invoke(TBaseVirtualTree* Sender, PVirtualNode Node, void * Data, bool &Abort) = 0 ;<br/>
};<br/>

Comment: from VirtualTrees.hpp  __interface TVTGetNodeProc;  
typedef System::DelphiInterface<TVTGetNodeProc> _di_TVTGetNodeProc;  
__interface TVTGetNodeProc  : public System::IInterface  
{  
public:  
virtual void __fastcall Invoke(TBaseVirtualTree* Sender, PVirtualNode Node, void * Data, bool &Abort) = 0 ;  
};

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use what Delphi/C++Builder calls a method pointer or `__closure`.  Virtual Treeview expects an anonymous method.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14975415/25507) for more details.

I *think* that creating an anonymous method in C++Builder involves subclassing from [TProc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.TProc) and implementing the Invoke method, but it seems to be very poorly documented.

If subclassing TProc doesn't work or is too hard to figure out, I can think of a couple of options:

- Hack the Virtual Treeview source to create an IterateSubtree overload taking a method pointer.
- Ask a new question on Stack Overflow in hopes that someone else knows how to create a Delphi anonymous method in C++Builder.

Comment: "*it seems to be very poorly documented*" - Have you read [How to Handle Delphi Anonymous Methods in C++](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B) in Embarcadero's documentation?

Answer (score 0):

thanks very much`

i have found the solution

```
typedef void (*TIterateSubtreeCallBack)(TBaseVirtualTree*, PVirtualNode Node, void *_Data, bool &Abort);   

class TMyVTGetNodeProcRef : public TCppInterfacedObject<TVTGetNodeProc>    
{
private:   
  TIterateSubtreeCallBack callback;   
public:   
  TMyVTGetNodeProcRef(TIterateSubtreeCallBack _callback) : callback(_callback) {}    
  INTFOBJECT_IMPL_IUNKNOWN(TInterfacedObject);   

  void __fastcall Invoke(TBaseVirtualTree* Sender, TVirtualNode *Node, void *Data, bool &Abort)   
  {   
    return callback(Sender, Node, Data, Abort);   
  }   
};   

void __fastcall TMyForm::BuSearchClick(TObject *)   
{   
  Node= MyTreeView->IterateSubtree(NULL, new TMyVTGetNodeProcRef(SearchDataId), (void*)&PNodeData, TVirtualNodeStates(), false, false);   
}   

void TMyForm::SearchDataId(TBaseVirtualTree*Tr, PVirtualNode Node, void *_Data, bool &Abort)   
{   
 put my code ...   
}   
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```